# Jquery Click Events Fires Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/q6on9zh6/1/) and let me know why the click events on `#pre` and `#nex` only firing once!

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
$("#month").html(months[n]);

$(".row").on('click' , '#pre',  function(){
    $("#month").html(months[n-1]);
});

$("#nex").on('click' , function(){
  $("#month").html(months[n+1]);
});
```

I also tried to use the delegate method on `#pre` which again didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decrement and increment the value of `n` for this to work. You also need to make sure that you are not outside the bounds of the array when you do so, otherwise you will get an index out of range exception.

```
$(".row").on('click' , '#pre',  function(){
    n = (n === 0) ? months.length - 1 : n - 1;
    $("#month").html(months[n]);
});

$("#nex").on('click' , function(){
    n = (n === months.length - 1) ? 0 : n + 1;
    $("#month").html(months[n]);
});
```

Comment: if you put it before of `$("#month").html(months[n+1]);` you can use only `n` `$("#month").html(months[n]);`

Comment: I suppose the n += 1 is slightly more readable, but the n++ is not much less unreadable and it's quicker to type.

Comment: Thanks James but can you also let me know how to reset the loop at the end I mean after the last month and first the code switching stops is there any way to restart the month at end or first?

Comment: ... It 's just a detail ... everyone uses the syntax they prefer, but as you learn all the possibilities... you are welcome James :).

Comment: @Suffii I've updated the code. This should now reset the loop at then start and end.

Comment: @JamesHay "is not much less unreadable" so that would be `n-+--+` right? ;)

Comment: @Edward How about "is not dramatically less readable"? I was thinking more along the lines of `n = (n===n)? (function(a){return a + 1;})(n) : n;`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the value of n, so you're always going to get last month from today.
Get the current value of #month first in your onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

Your events are firing - you are just setting the same value each time they fire. try adding n+=1 and n-=1 in your events to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

i am edit your code and now working 
you should change counter value will each click ..

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]; 
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();

```
$("#month").html(months[n]);

$(".row").on('click' , '#pre',  function(){
    $("#month").html(months[n-1]);
    n=n-1
});

$("#nex").on('click' , function(){
  $("#month").html(months[n+1]);
    n=n+1
});
```